# Como retornar informações apagadas com softdelete dentro de uma relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Existe um model na minha aplicação chamada pagamento que pertence à um user. Eu puxo as informações com

```
Pagamento::latest()->with('user');
```

Dessa forma se um usuário for apagado, mesmo que ele já esteja com soft delete, ele não é retornado. Como retorná-lo junto com os pagamentos? 
Então, basicamente eu quero incluir usuários deletados pelo soft-delete nessa query. Alguma forma de colocar um `withTrashed()` para o usuário nessa query.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não deseja que, sempre que chamar esse relacionamento, ele também traga os registros apagados, como no caso de adicionar `withTrashes()` ao definir o relacionamento no modelo, você pode fazê-lo na query:

```
Pagamento::with(['user' => function ($q) {
   $q->withTrashed();
}])->latest();
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido incluindo -`>withTrashed` na relation.

No `Pagamento.php:`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withTrashed();
}
```

Comment: Foi resolvido e criado outro! Se não pode excluir usuário se ele tem relação compreende?

Comment: Acho que não @VirgilioNovic porque ele tá usando o softDelete do Laravel, os dados do usuário vão continuar no banco, apenas a coluna `deleted_at` será preenchida e esse usuário não será exibido dentro do sistema se ele não utilizar essa função do `withTrashed`

Comment: Sim @KayoBruno mas, o que foi feito nessa resposta limita o usuario fazer somente esse caminho, o melhor seria criar um query scope para isso, ou um relacionamento próprio.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic concordo com você que criar um query scope para isso seria bem melhor, não estou dizendo que você tá errado só não entendi quando você disse "limita o usuario fazer somente esse caminho". kkkk

Comment: porque geralmente @KayoBruno a função de relação `user` é para trazer os usuários e você se limita com um query a mais na função. é isso...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic agora entendi, sim realmente faz todo sentido. Obrigado por ter esclarecido mesmo eu tendo demorado pra entender rsrsr.